# Nodejs attempting to populate user, however no success

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

For my application, I successfully manage to reference other documents, and store them in my database(mongodb) as an objectid. However when attempting to use .populate the population is not occurring. Here is my population code:

```
 User
    .find()
    .populate([
        {path: 'followers'},
        {path: 'following'}
    ])
```

Comment: Please share the users mongoose schema

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

"
`Story.`
 `find().` 
 `populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'name' }).`
 `populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'email' });`
   `// The above is equivalent to:` 
    `Story.find().populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'email' });`

"

I never used MongoDB but maybe this snippet from this link can help.